# Counterexample to Eisenstein criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, examples-counterexamples, irreducible-polynomials

We know Eisenstein criterion about irreducibility of polynomials: if $q(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots +a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is such that $\exists p$ prime number with $ p \mid a_{i} \ \forall i \ , \ p^2 \nmid a_0$ then $q(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
The question is : how to find a counterexample in the case $p$ is not a prime ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: if $p$ is not a prime the criterion is false. I need a reducible polynomial that verifies the criterion's condition with $p$ not prime

Comment: a bit silly, but $p=4$, $q(x)=x^2-4$

Comment: @boris Your question makes no sense, $p$ is a bounded variable.

Comment: I think he's asking for an example that demonstrates "if you forget about $p$ being prime, things go wrong."

Comment: @rschwieb Oh, thanks.

Comment: maybe something positive: if $p$ is a prime, $p^k$ divides every $a_i$ and $p^{k+1}$ doesn't divide $a_0$, **and** $gcd(n,k)=1$, then $q$ is irreducible (as follows from it's Newton polygon)

Comment: I changed \ | \ to \mid and \not | to \nmid.  Both are standard.

Comment: @Git Gud: This question makes sense. if one removes condition "$p$ is prime" by "$p$ is an arbitrary integer" then the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like $(x-2)(x+2)=x^2-4$ for $p=4$?

Method used to find this counterexample:

Thought: Keep things simple. Just have a monic leading term and then a constant.
Asked self: Do I know any easy factorizations for binomials?
Thought: Of course: $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$
Completed: Use $a=x$ and pick any $b$ but make sure $b^2\neq 1$ and use $p=b^2$

Comment: Elapsed time < 2 seconds.